# How can I display an image from internal storge in an ImageView() on Android?

Tags: android

I want to display an image that is in my internal storage but I keep getting an error that "there is no such file of directory". I don't know what to set as the path to the file.

This is what I have:

```
pButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View view) {
                    pBox.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/internalstorage/pictures/cat.jpg"));

            }
```

Comment: First, you need to determine if you are really using [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) (e.g., your app downloaded the image) or [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your path is not correct get storage path through this code and then add your picture path with this.

```
File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String path = extStore.getPath() + "/pictures/cat.jpg"
```

Then use this path in

```
pBox.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path));
```

Hope this will solve your solution.